Are Teichmuller elements needed for universal Witt vectors?
Are Teichmuller elements used with or needed for universal Witt vectors?
If so, what prime number p is used for determining the Teichmuller elements?
And, if so, why are they needed? (It seems that the original elements lifted with Witt polynomials is all that is needed, without also replacing the original elements by Teichmuller elements.)
